# Two node BizTalk Server setup on Azure IaaS, why so slow?

Tags: sql, azure, biztalk, biztalk-2013r2

I have three servers on azure, one for SQL 2014 with Enterprise SSO on it, one for BizTalk server 1, one for BizTalk server 2, everything works, just refresh the host instance take way over 2 minute in the admin console, anyone know why? what I did wrong?

They are on the same virtual network, the BizTalk version is 2013 R2 Enterprise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is because of firewall, i believe, once turned off, everything works!